# Cucumber test not running

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am working on my first feature file/selenium project.

I have created a feature file and runner class.

```html
package cucumberpkg2;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions
(features="Features") 
public class Runner {

}
```

I have the feature file test.feature

```
Feature: Login screen

  Scenario Outline: Successful login
    Given User is on Login page
    When User enters valid UserName and Password
    And Clicks the login button
    Then User landed on the home page
```

But whenever I try to run the TestRunner class as a JUnit test, I get the error:

Test class not found in selected project.

Comment: you also need to specify glue as to where your step definitions resides for the feature file as `glue={"packagename.classname"},` in @CucumberOptions

Comment: @kushal. `glue` option is not mandatory to test the Cucumber project binding. But `glue` is mandatory when you want to test the complete implementation :) Thanks

Comment: @dev, I know that glue isn't mandatory some times but I don't understand your statement :/

Comment: if you have same structure in resource file as in java for implementations of those featuers you don't need glue statement, otherwise you required it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution to your Question:

1. As per the current documentation of [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference) you may require to change the keyword `Scenario Outline` to `Scenario` in `test.feature` file.
2. Though you mentioned about `TestRunner` class but your code speaks about `Runner` class being implemented as `public class Runner`, be sure which class file are you executing as `JUnit test`.
3. You may require to change `@CucumberOptions` to `@Cucumber.Options` for previous versions (recent versions work with `@CucumberOptions`)
4. Put the following 2 parts in a single line as `@Cucumber.Options
   (features="Features")`
5. As you would be mentioning `@Cucumber.Options(features="Features")` ensure that your feature file is placed inside `Features` sub-directory within the Project Directory.
6. So you will be having, `test.feature` file within `Features` sub-directory with the following code:

   ```
   Feature: Login screen
       Scenario: Successful login
       Given User is on Login page
       When User enters valid UserName and Password
       And Clicks the login button
       Then User landed on the home page
   ```
7. Your `Runner` class will look like:

   ```
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
   @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
   @CucumberOptions(features="Features")
   public class Runner {

   }
   ```
8. Finally when you will execute `Runner` class as a JUnit test you will see the following message on your console:

   ```
   You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

   @Given("^User is on Login page$")
   public void User_is_on_Login_page() throws Throwable {
       // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
       throw new PendingException();
   }

   @When("^User enters valid UserName and Password$")
   public void User_enters_valid_UserName_and_Password() throws Throwable {
       // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
       throw new PendingException();
   }

   @When("^Clicks the login button$")
   public void Clicks_the_login_button() throws Throwable {
       // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
       throw new PendingException();
   }

   @Then("^User landed on the home page$")
   public void User_landed_on_the_home_page() throws Throwable {
       // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
       throw new PendingException();
   }
   ```
9. These warnings can be taken care easily by implementing the `glue` options to Cucumber.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide full path of the feature file as mentioned below.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
                features = {"src/test/resources/com/gaurang/steps/demo.feature",
                            "src/test/resources/com/gaurang/steps/demo1.feature"
                            }
                )
public class RunAllTest {

}
```

or if you have too many feature files the best way is to provide tags to feature file and then use those tags to run as mentioned below .

```
@userRegistrations
Feature: User Registration
```

**RunAllTest.java**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags={"@userRegistrations"})
public class RunAllTest {
}
```

And you can use multiple tags

Comment: Your solution will take care of only `demo.feature` (one) feature file, what if you have got multiple feature file :)

Comment: @Dev i takes multiple feature file, I have updated the answer. However the better thing would be to use Tags. provide tags to feature and then use them.

Comment: Yup, you are right :) rather I would pass the name of folder containing the features