# How are the selenium based tests/scripts executed for a enterprise/project/application?

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, cucumber, testng

It may sound a very basic question,how does selenium scripts are executed for a enterprise/project/application?
Scripts are created in java using locators etc and lots of tests are created.Tests are structured via TestNG and i can run these test via IDE(eclipse for me) using Run as " TestNG suite" . As i am in learning phase for selenium i am curious, if this is the only way or some other process as well.
I want to understand how the complete packaging/deployment/execution of scripts happens along with other dependencies like additional libraries for TestNG or excel utilities etc(using maven or others).

I tried searching on web , but nothing of this sort is available or i am not searching the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium tests/scripts of any enterprise/project/application are executed with the help of the components used to develop the *Test Framework*. There are numerous *Tools* and *Frameworks* available which can be integrated to execute the *Selenium* related *test*. A few of them are as follows:

- *Tests* can be executed as a standalone *Java* program or through *TestNG*. You can find a relevant discussion in [How to write Selenium Java Application code in IDE through main() and TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018053/how-to-write-selenium-java-application-code-in-ide-through-main-and-testng/48018950#48018950)
- You can also integrate [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) to execute the *Tests*. You can find a relevant discussion in [How to start FireFoxDriver using Selenium 3.4.0 using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757984/how-to-start-firefoxdriver-using-selenium-3-4-0-using-maven/43759644#43759644)
- You can also integrate [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) to execute the *Tests*. You can find a relevant discussion in [Need correct step for Bat file creation using (TestNG.xml + Maven)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081849/need-correct-step-for-bat-file-creation-using-testng-xml-maven)
- You can also integrate [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) to execute the *Tests*. You can find a relevant discussion in [Cucumber test not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966680/cucumber-test-not-running/43977018#43977018)